# How do you disable a control within a repeater

Tags: asp.net, repeater, itemtemplate

I have a repeater with a `CheckBox` and a `TextBox`, that I am binding to a data source. Depending on conditions from the code behind, I want to be able to disable the `CheckBox` and `TextBox` dynamically.

Currently this is what I have within the `<ItemTemplate>`:

```html
<td>
    <asp:CheckBox runat="server" 
        onclick="checkbox(this); CheckChildren(this);" 
        Enabled='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DISABLE") %>' 
        Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CTEXT") %>' 
        Value='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CVALUE") %>' />
</td>

<td>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" 
        onkeyup="AppendValues(this);" 
        Enabled='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DISABLE") %>' 
        Width="35px" 
        MaxLength="3" 
        Name='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CNAME") %>' 
        CValue='<%3DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CNTVALUE") %>'>
    </asp:TextBox>
</td>
```

The `#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DISABLE")` is being set to the string value of "true" on the code behind yet when the code is ran, I receive an `InvalidCastException` exception.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a `boolean` value to the `Enabled` property. Try something like this

```
bool.Parse(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DISABLE").ToString())
```

Comment: no, you have to put this in your aspx/ascx file, inside your <%# %> declaration